# Add text at the end of the logs

Tags: rsyslog

I actually use Rsyslog 8.24 and I configured my rsyslog to accept logs from multiples input/sources.

I want to add the syslog hostname at the end of every logs.

**Example** :

- Old log : timestamps, header, message
- New log : timestamps, header, message syslog.domain.local

I know that the variable $myhostname or $MYHOSTNAME should return the hostname of the syslog but I don't understand how to implement this and add the syslog hostname at the end of each log.

Comment: You either have to adjust the message on the system you're sending the logs from. Another option would be to look at the logs on your syslog server and see where they're coming from, and then define a name for each host. 

If you need further help, please **provide more information**.

Comment: I can't modify message from the hosts.
I managed to add the syslog hostname at the end of the logs (see my answer below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do what I wanted by adding the following template and binding it in the ruleset :

```
template (name="LogsFormat" type="string" string="%TIMESTAMP% %$year% %syslogtag% %msg% <SYSLOG_HOSTNAME>:%$myhostname%\n")

ruleset(name="RemoteLogPort") {
        if (re_match($msg, "AP:aaa-bbbb-ccc-dddd-ap")) then {
                action(type="omfile" dynaFile="ArubaNetworksPath" template="LogsFormat")
        }
}
```

PS : ArubaNetworksPath is also a template defining the log path.